# How to populate table with mysql?

Tags: php, html, while-loop, html-table

Below is my code:

```
<?php
include 'db_table.php';
include 'main.php';

if(isset($_GET['userid']) || (isset($_SESSION['userid'])))
  {
    if ((!empty($_GET['userid'])) || (!empty($_SESSION['userid'])) )  {


      if(!isset($_GET['userid']) ||  empty($_GET['userid']) )
        $userid=$_SESSION['userid'];
      else
        $userid=$_GET['userid'];


      $query = "SELECT * FROM status  WHERE userid = '$userid'";
      $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


      if(!$row){ echo "<li class='form-line' id='id_3'><div id='cid_3' class='form-input-wide'><div id='text_3' class='form-html'>No Status so Far </div></li><br>"; }
      else{

        echo "<table>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

          $finalstatus = $row['username']."   says : ".$row['status'];
          echo "<tr>";

          echo "<td class='form-line' id='id_3'><div id='cid_3' class='form-input-wide'><div id='text_3' class='form-html'>".$finalstatus."</div></td>" ;


          echo "</tr>";
        }// while

        echo "</table>";

      }// else
    }// empty
  } // isset

else{echo "<li class='form-line' id='id_3'><div id='cid_3' class='form-input-wide'><div id='text_3' class='form-html'>No Status so Far </div></li><br>";}
?>
```

When i use the above code , i only get the last status  present in the database . But i need the full status of the mysql table to be populated on my table

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes there. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: @MarcB i know that this is vulnerable. But currently i need someway to get all the status values in the table

Comment: Is the PHP code the same in both code blocks? You don't need to post the same thing twice.

Comment: You're not printing the first row, because you fetch it before going into the `while` loop. If you want to know if anything was found, use `mysql_num_rows()`.

Comment: sorry. i thought that it would be easy for others to figure out what is wrong. i guess while part of php has the error. so i posted the php code seperatly.

Comment: Problem isn't posting it separately, problem is posting it twice.

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_num_rows()` to test if anything was found.

```
      $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

      if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {

        echo "<li class='form-line' id='id_3'><div id='cid_3' class='form-input-wide'><div id='text_3' class='form-html'>No Status so Far </div></li><br>"; }
      else{

        echo "<table>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

          $finalstatus = $row['username']."   says : ".$row['status'];
          echo "<tr>";

          echo "<td class='form-line' id='id_3'><div id='cid_3' class='form-input-wide'><div id='text_3' class='form-html'>".$finalstatus."</div></td>" ;


          echo "</tr>";
        }// while

        echo "</table>";

      }// else
```